# include spaces rather than dashes in the case of a space

Tags: java

OK first I'd like to say I'm new to Java Development...
With that in mind I'm currently trying to make the value of tryWord include spaces rather than dashes in the case of a space in s. can anyone help me?

```
    String tryWord = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        tryWord += "-";
    }
    System.out.println(s + tryWord);

Value for s
------------
private static String randomOutput() {
    String array[] = new String[10];
    array[0] = "Hamlet";
    array[1] = "Mysts of Avalon";
    array[2] = "The Iliad";
    array[3] = "Tales from Edger Allan Poe";
    array[4] = "The Children of Hurin";
    array[5] = "The Red Badge of Courage";
    array[6] = "Of Mice and Men";
    array[7] =  "Utopia"; 
    array[8] =  "Chariots of the Gods";
    array[9] =  "a Brief History of Time";

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    String s = list.get(0);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to copy a List to shuffle it, and you don't need to shuffle the list to get one element. You can get a random element of an array without either of these.

Comment: What value do you want to be in tryWord to be at the end of the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace`  or  `replaceAll` in java,It will solve the problem

```
tryWord = s.replaceAll("\\s", "-");
```

Comment: Thank u for better answer.I will include this also

Comment: I think you actually want `\\s` instead of `\\S`.  The upper-case `S` means all *non*-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 tryWord.replace(oldChar, newChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   tryWord += s.charAt(i) == ' ' ? " " : "-";
```

This called the ternary expression `... ? ... : ...`, a kind of if ith char is space then space else dash.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
   tryWord += ' ';
} else {
   tryWord += '-';
}
```